AWS Cognito Authoriser gives a 401 for my access token but gives a 200 for IdToken
I just setup a cognito user pool and created a get API in API Gateway. Then created an Authorizer in cognito and added it to the API. However, it doesnt validate the access token but the IdToken.

Go with headers instead for authorization validation. Add them in the console as required. Provide the api-key while you call it and the problem is solved.
